# Panning not working in a FlowDocumentScrollViewer (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, touch

I have a FlowDocument inside a FlowDocumentScrollViewer.  I can see the scrollbars and use them to scroll text.  To enable panning using **touch gestures**, I set `ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both"`.  But that only works if there is an image in the FlowDocument, and if I start the touch gesture from the image.  In other words, I can pan by pressing, moving and releasing, but only if when I press, my finger touches an image.  If I first press in the text, nothing happens (not able to scroll).

Here's the XAML code:

```xml
   <Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Height="350" IsSelectionEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both">
            <FlowDocument Background="Ivory" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20">
                <Section >
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 0</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 2</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 3</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 4</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 5</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 6</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 7</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 8</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 9</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 10</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 11</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 12</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 13</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 14</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 15</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 16</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 17</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 18</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 19</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 20</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 21</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 22</Paragraph>
                    <Paragraph>Paragraph 23</Paragraph>
                </Section>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Using a `<TextBlock>` and setting `ScrollViewer.PanningMode` works fine, but I need to use `<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>`.

It looks like `<Paragraph>` elements somehow trap events.

Apart from implementing a workaround (which gives poor user experience), how can we fix that?

Thank you

Comment: To be precise, what you mean is panning isn't working when you touch paragraphs. If you handle previewmousedown on the document does that fire?

Comment: I added some details in the question.  I also tried handling the MouseDown event, and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the paragraphs grab any touch down event. I don't have any touch device to test. But I cannot scroll the FlowDocumentScrollViewer with mouse inside the document.

A likely work round is to handle preview events and scroll the relevant scrollviewer by the delta moved.

Handlers here deal with both mouse and touch.

```
    bool IsScrolling = false; 
    Point LastPoint;
    private void FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleDown(sender);
    }

    private void HandleDown(object sender)
    {
        var sv = sender as FlowDocumentScrollViewer;
        if (sender != null)
        {
            IsScrolling = true;
            LastPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(sv);
        }
    }

    private void FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleMove(sender);
    }

    private void FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsScrolling = false;
    }

    private void FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleDown(sender);
    }

    private void FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        IsScrolling = false;
    }

    private void FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleMove(sender);
    }

    private void HandleMove(object sender)
    {
        var fdsv = sender as FlowDocumentScrollViewer;
        if (fdsv == null || !IsScrolling)
        {
            return;
        }
        var ThisPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(fdsv);
        double dY = (ThisPoint.Y - LastPoint.Y);
        double dX = (ThisPoint.X - LastPoint.X);

        ScrollViewer sv = fdsv.GetChildOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset - dY);
        LastPoint = ThisPoint;
    }
```

Handle those events on the FlowDocumentScrollViewer

```
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Height="350" 
                              IsSelectionEnabled="False" 
                              ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both"
                              PreviewMouseDown ="FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown"
                              PreviewTouchDown="FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchDown"
                              PreviewMouseUp="FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewMouseUp"
                              PreviewTouchUp="FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchUp"
                              PreviewMouseMove="FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewMouseMove"
                              PreviewTouchMove="FlowDocumentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchMove"
                              >
```

With these in place, I can drag and scroll with mouse.

Getchildoftype

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I already implemented a similar workaround, but I would prefer the real behavior, because it's more user-friendly.  Like you said, maybe Paragraph elements capture touch events, I'll have a look.

Comment: I don't think you can make them ishittestvisible false.